# Make 1 page objects Two Elements ID's to 1 page object Variable

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

I am using the page object Gem with Watir. During testing I found that I have a field that has the same contents that show in the same location but have separate unique ID's. The difference is before you get to the page.

I tried using Xpaths:

```
select_list(:selectionSpecial, :xpath => "//select[@id='t_id9' OR @id='t_id7']")
```

But was met with a script error.

They are static ID's but I want to force them into one variable since that would allow me to use **"populate_page_with"** feature.

I have a long winded way currently, but I am fishing for a more efficient way that works with the page object Features.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of using xpath can work. The problem is the syntax errors in the xpath selector. It should be:

```
"//select[@id='t_id9' or @id='t_id7']"
```

Note:

- The start should be a `//` rather than a `\`
- Using `or` is case-sensitive; it has to be lower case
- There was also a missing closing `'` for the first id attribute

Personally, I find css and xpath selectors harder to use. I would go with the id locator with a regex. The following gives the same results, but some will find it easier to read.

```
select_list(:selectionSpecial, :id => /^t_id(7|9)$/)
```

Comment: sorry the // was from me not putting indents around it. Thanks for the answer I will give it a shot!!